# AttributeError: 'FeeSchedulePage' object has no attribute 'create'

Tags: python

When I try call `feeSchedulePage.create()` I'm getting the error **`AttributeError: 'FeeSchedulePage' object has no attribute 'create'`**

---

**fee_schedule_page.py**

```
class FeeSchedulePage(Page):

  def enter_name(self, name):

      self.find_element(*FeeScheduleLocators.NAME).send_keys(name)


  def create(self):

      self.enter_name("a")
```

**test_create_fee_schedule.py**

```
class TestCreateFeeSchedule:

  def test_03_CreateFeeSchedule(self):

      feeSchedulePage = FeeSchedulePage(self.driver)
      feeSchedulePage.create()
```

---

Any ideia for this?

Comment: You are mixing tabs and spaces. `def create` uses a tab (as well as spaces), and is indented further than you think (8 spaces, not 4).

Comment: Don't mix tabs and spaces. Run Python with the `-tt` command-line switch and fix the errors that points out. Convert all tabs to spaces in your editor, and configure your editor to only use spaces when indenting.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MartijnPieters :) Solved my problem.